# What values in an application should be configurable?

Tags: design, coding-standards, configuration

What values in an application should be configurable, or otherwise not hard coded?  Does this differ based on application type (batch vs UI) and are there any published standards or guidance on this topic (IEEE, ACM, vendor, etc)?

Answer (score 9):

There are two extremes:

1. Hard-code everything.  This has the advantage of being easy and avoids the overhead of configuration.  The disadvantages are obvious: maintainability, hot-deploying config changes, varying settings across environments, etc.
2. Make everything a configuration setting.  This has the most flexibility at the cost of having large configuration files with settings that rarely and sometimes never change.

A guideline is tough to have because it varies case-by-case.

Some questions to ask for each setting:

- How likely is this to change?  More likely suggests config, less likely suggests a code constant may be acceptable.
- If it changes, do we need immediate result or can we wait for a full build and redeploy?  If a rebuild and deploy is acceptable, then a code constant may be acceptable.
- Would the value ever need to be different across different environments?  If so, you obviously can't put it in your code unless your code knows about environments, which is not a great idea in my mind.
- Is the value itself dictated by a business rule?  For example, page size when paginating a list is likely to be spelled out by a requirements spec.  If it is, then the need to see a change take effect immediately is probably non-existent.  The change is likely to be tracked via product requirement change control and so embedding the value in code is probably wise.
- If the setting is related to performance, you probably want it to be hot/field serviceable, so configuration is the way to go.

When I recommend storing settings in code, I presume you would use a centralized constant and not hard-code in each place that uses it.

I'll share a funny story of bad constant use that this reminds me of.  I have seen code where a constant is passed for page size.  The constant is named HUNDRED_STRING.  HUNDRED_STRING is of course set to "100".  I can't wait to see what happens when somebody sets HUNDRED_STRING = "200" and the world goes crazy.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, the more the value is expected to have to change, the more likely I'd make it a config setting rather than hard-coding it. I generally have a three-strikes rule; Hard-code it first because that's easy, then change it once on the first user request, and on the next change after that, refactor it into a config value that can be changed in-place without another code update.

Other factors that would lead me toward hard-coding:

- The value is an implementation detail. If your end users don't care what its value is, don't expose it.
- The value is a "universal constant" for the system; maybe not something mathematical like pi or *e*, but a value that, if it ever *did* change, would require substantial code edits anyway.
- The program doesn't use shared config settings, and it's easier/safer to push a full update than to have the users update their local configs. I have a couple of ClickOnce apps that are hard to access in the filesystem by design, while a publish and upgrade is relatively easy. Using config settings for machine-independent values is purely for my benefit as a coder in these circumstances.

Factors that lead me toward configuration settings (whether in a local file or a shared DB):

- Uptime is critical. Business-critical services that can only be taken down for maintenance at very un-businesslike hours of the night or weekend should be designed with as few reasons to perform such maintenance as possible. So, not only should you make controlling values that could change independent of other code into config values, the service should be designed to refresh these values and change its configuration periodically, so you don't even need a manual restart.
- The value varies between installations. The phone number of the workstation on which the software is installed is an obvious example of something that is never OK to hard-code.
- The value is part of a system designed to be customizable. For instance, programs with multiple child windows like an MDI should remember the positions of different types of windows when they're closed, and re-open the next one of that type in the same spot. This may not be user-configurable, but don't just hard-code unless your users are trained specifically toward a particular layout.